# What is causing my cat's urine smell to be so overwhelming?

Tags: cats, health

When my cat urinates, the odor permeates the house, and hangs around.  I have switched cat litters, trying all different kinds, but it does not help.  I suspect it is due to the cat food fed to my cat.

When I fed him a cheaper cat food a week or so ago, the odor was gone.  I fed him a more expensive brand now, and the odor is back.

What is causing the urine odor to be strong with the more expensive cat food?

Comment: What are the two cat foods you feed your cat?

Comment: Is your cat spayed or neutered? The food change could be a coincidence.